# extracting words from a sentence using indexOf and substring and storing them in an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, substring, indexof

Here is what I have so far for this part of my program;

```
String text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter a sentence");

String newWord = "";
char space = '_';
int count = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
{
  int found = text.indexOf(space, i);

  int start = found + 1; // start location of substring after a space
  int end = text.indexOf(space, start); // end of word
  count = end + 1;
}
  while(count < text.length())
  {

newWord[count] = text.substring(start, end); 

  count++;

}

System.out.println(newWord[count]);
```

Comment: This looks like a code/homework dump to me. Original poster, please tell us *precisely* where you're stuck and ask a specific answerable question soon else this question will likely be closed soon.

Comment: This is part of a method I am trying to get to work. I want to split a sentence into individual words and put these words into an array

Comment: In what way does it not do what you want? What exactly are you hoping that the SO community will do for you? (One thing we will *not* do is to do your homework for you.)

Comment: `newWord` is not an array, so trying to address it with `newWord[count]` won't even compile...

Comment: I am not asking you to do my homework for me I am asking you to give me some direction as to why it is not working and what I could do to make it work.

Comment: Then in your original post, ask a specific question. All you've got in the original post is your assignment requirements and code. That's not a valid question still.

Comment: how is that not a valid question the question was "Extracting words from a String using indexOf and substring then storing them in an array" I thought it was pretty self explanatory.

Comment: That's not a question: that's an assignment and a homework dump. A valid stackoverflow question is where you show us your attempt to solve it and tell us *exactly* what stumps you. It doesn't look like you have even tried.

Comment: What are you talking about you obviously didn't even look at what I had posted because there was clearly an attempt there. That was not an entire assignment it was a very small part of an assignment I was having problems with that I posted and wanted someone to give me constructive help and criticism not rude comments like your own if you know so much how come you couldn't be constructive and help?

Comment: obviously you were not intelligent to figure out the question. Seems like it was pretty self explanatory!

Answer (score 2):

to split a sentence, use String's .split() method

```
String [] splitter = text.split(" ");
```

this will break the sentence based on spaces. Then you can do whatever you need to the array

Comment: I am aware of that method but since I can not use it for this assignment

Comment: ahh ok, was wondering...I'm gonna leave this up just so no one else will do again

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a sentence");
int count = 0;
char space = ' ';

int index = 0;
do 
{
   ++ count;
   ++ index;
   index = text.indexOf(space, index);
}
while (index != -1);

    String[] array = new String[count];
    index = 0;
    int endIndex = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
      endIndex = text.indexOf(space, index);

      if(endIndex == -1)
     {
       array[i] = text.substring(index);
     }else{
       array[i] = text.substring(index, endIndex);
     }

     index = endIndex + 1;
    }
    for(String s : array)
    {
      System.out.println(s);
    }
```